# Add button to progressDialog already showed

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I would like to add this negative button, for example, but 3 seconds after.

It is possible or I have to dismiss this `progressDialog` and open a new dialog?

I tried that:

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this,
            R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Bla bla bla ...");

    progressDialog.show();

    progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    SystemClock.sleep(3000);

    progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19359078/10752944) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the button hidden and after opening the dialog use this code

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } 
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: or in your case move  progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
 inside timer